# Synaptics Touchpad becomes unresponsive immediately after login

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, synaptics

So, my touchpad works just fine when on login screen, but buttons and touchpad are completely unusable. Here's the kicker: the touchpad is NOT DISABLED. This occurred first after I locked the laptop and closed the lid while on battery power.

**Please see the comment below, this fixed it for me.**

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself! I use 12.10, and the gsettings code syntax appears to differ slightly from 12.04. 12.10 users, try opening terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and typing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled 'true'
```